# How to evaluate a JCoStructure?

Tags: java, jco

I have the following structure:

```
|----------|----------|----|---|
| STRUCTURE 'NameOfStructur'   |
|----------|----------|----|---|
|Num       |A         |B   |C  |
|----------|----------|----|---|
|0123456789|0123456789|0123|456|
|----------|----------|----|---|
|          |          |    |   |
|----------|----------|----|---|
```

which I print with:

```java
JCoStructure struct = exportParameters.getStructure(paramName);
System.out.println(struct.toString());
```

and with:

```java
JCoStructure struct = exportParameters.getStructure(paramName);

JCoFieldIterator fieldIt = struct.getFieldIterator();

while (fieldIt.hasNextField()) {
    JCoField field = fieldIt.nextField();
    System.out.println(field.getName());
}
```

I receive the attribute names (`Num`, `A`, `B`, `C`) but I am still not able to get the values from this struct. `field.getValue()` just returns `null` and `field.toString()` delivers an object reference value.

Does anybody know how to receive this values?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer is simple,

```
|0123456789|0123456789|0123|456|
```

is just like a parting line on every "empty" and non empty table/structure when printing it with "toString()". Thought this are entries on our test-sap-system. So it is completly correct, that I will receive for every entry a "null" because these datastructures are empty yet.

So basically @Trixx is completly right about how to retrieve values from JCoStructures/JCoFields but my problem wasn't that I was not able to retrieve the correct methods from the documentation but that it wasn't documented that the line that was printed out was a separation line and not as I thought a tuple of example data.

Answer (score 4):

`JCoField.getName()` gets the field's name and for the field's value use an appropriate getter-method, e.g. `JCoField.getString()` should always work. If feasible, other getter-methods will do a type conversion on-the-fly, e.g. `JCoField.getInt()` will work and return a primitive int 623521, if the field contains the string "623521" as a value.

In your example, all the fields in the structure are currently empty, so `JCoField.getString()` will return "".

By the way, you do not need to use the field iterator. You can also directly access the field values from the `JCoStructure` by using the field's name or its index, e.g. use `JCoStructure.getString("Num")` or `JCoStructure.getString(0)`.

Comment: Yep, but my problem was that I tried for ours to receive the values out of an empty table, because I thought that the numbers are not just a room divider but actual entries. Everything else I already learned from all the examples found on the internet, but thank you anyway :)